# How to detect browser in Ember

Tags: ember.js, npm, browser-detection, bowser

Does Ember have built-in way to detect browser? Something like this if using this [library(bowser)](https://github.com/ded/bowser)

```
    if (bowser.msie) {
        ...
    } else if (bowser.gecko) {
        ...
    } else if (bowser.webkit) {
        ...
    }
```

Or, I can just `npm install bowser`, then import it and use it in Ember

Answer (score 4):

I guess there won't be any builtin way in ember to detect browser AFAIK. Usually this kind of job will be delegated to ember addon, may be try [ember-browser-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-browser-checker) if this is not fulfilled your requirement then you can consider any npm/bower libraries like you found `bowser`.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a little [browsercheck as service](https://gist.github.com/cstengel88/db631a372f1505052c127990a6da810b) be aware that this is not secure, but works for simple needs

Answer (score 1):

[Ember UserAgent](https://github.com/willviles/ember-useragent) is an Ember addon which exposes a `userAgent` service, making it easy to detect browser, device, OS and more.

It works in both browser & Fastboot environments and is as simple as:

```
const userAgent = this.get('userAgent');

userAgent.get('browser.isChrome'); // Boolean
userAgent.get('engine.isWebKit'); // Boolean
userAgent.get('os.info'); // => { name: 'Ubuntu', version: '11.10' }
userAgent.getDevice(); // => { model: 'iPhone 7', type: 'mobile', vendor: 'Apple'}
```